# Mac OS X Mavericks Issue when Setting Virtual Hosts

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, virtualhost

I have been trying to figure out this issue for some time.

I currently have a successful site running on the virtual host.
I am trying to add a new virtual host for a new website I am developing locally and am unable to figure out how to obtain the new site. My browser is unable to find the website.

Below is my process:

1. Open up terminal
2. type the following:

   ```
   sudo apachectl start
   ```
3. Then I go into the Virtual host:

   sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
4. Go through below and configure:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@workingexample.com
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/Example/folder"
   ServerName dev.workingexample.com
   ServerAlias dev.workingexample.com
   <Directory />
   Allow from all </Directory></VirtualHost>
   ```

Below is what is not working:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.broken.com

    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/broken"
    ServerName dev.broken.com
    ServerAlias dev.broken.com
    <Directory />
    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

When i go to dev.workingexample.com/test I am able to see the fully functioning site.
When I go to dev.broken.com/helloworld.html - the site does not appear.

I am able to find the site through http: //local host/~me/parentfolder/.

Comment: You don't mention restarting/reloading Apache after each configuration change. Do you do that? It doesn't refresh its configuration from the file automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I do restart apache after each configure change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache configuration merely prepares and instructs Apache to handle incoming requests for that particular (virtual) domain, should it receive one. It does not tell your computer/browser how to find that domain. Unless you have registered `dev.broken.com` in the DNS system, your computer doesn't know how to find that domain.

Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add the domain to the local loopback address:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost dev.broken.com
```

That overrides DNS lookups and tells your system that `dev.broken.com` resolves to your local machine. Make sure you leave `localhost` in the list for `127.0.0.1`, or a bunch of stuff will probably break. Add any further virtual host domains to the end of that list.